# extract value from the url by using a regex

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have this string value

```
var x = '/index.cfm?act=page1.showdata';
```

want to extract `page1`

if i had to use it as simple, i am use contains to find it and make it work, but i really want to use regex to find that value and put it into a variable,

using coldfusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex. Every query string parameter is available in the `url` scope. They're all already variables.

```
<cfdump var="#url#">
```

This dumps a struct whose keys are the parameters.

So the CF variable `url.act` has a value (string) of `page1.showdata`.

What else do you need than that?